# Execute stored procedure if result exists

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to have some help with an existing stored procedure where I would like to get an output from where I have matching records from the table `[DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots]` where we have matching records for `CrossbarRouter = @CrossbarRouter` which is part of stored procedure,

I want to execute the stored procedure `[StateMachine].[UpdateSnapshots]` only if `@OUT` result set matches `@Crossbar` parameter.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @OUT NVARCHAR(100); 

CREATE PROCEDURE [StateMachine].[UpdateSnapshots] 
    @SystemName [NVARCHAR](128), 
    @IntrestingEvents VARCHAR(128), 
    @StateMachine_JSON [NVARCHAR](MAX),
    @StateMachine_Object [NVARCHAR](MAX),
    @CrossbarRouter VARCHAR(128)
AS
    SET @OUT = (SELECT [CrossbarRouter] 
                FROM [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots] 
                WHERE CrossbarRouter = @CrossbarRouter)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots] 
               WHERE SystemName = @SystemName)
        UPDATE [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots]
        SET IntrestingEvents = @IntrestingEvents, 
            StateMachine_JSON = @StateMachine_JSON, 
            StateMachine_Object = @StateMachine_Object, 
            CrossbarRouter = @CrossbarRouter
        WHERE SystemName = @SystemName;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots] (SystemName, IntrestingEvents, StateMachine_JSON, StateMachine_Object, CrossbarRouter)
        VALUES (@SystemName, @IntrestingEvents, @StateMachine_JSON, @StateMachine_Object, @CrossbarRouter);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can RETURN if there is no match:

```
SELECT @OUT = [CrossbarRouter] 
    FROM [DVMT30_EVENT_PROCESSOR].[StateMachine].[Snapshots] 
    WHERE CrossbarRouter = @CrossbarRouter

IF @OUT IS NULL 
    RETURN 0;
```